# Launch instance over reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, reserved

I bought a reserved instance t2.Micro for Windows, and now I want to create a new instance with similar features for apply it.
In root storage get 30GB size for defect. Can I increase the value to have more storage capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can increase the disk size of your reserved instance. However you will be billed for the additional storage. Reserved instance capacity is reserved for CPU, RAM (and Bandwidth). Disk is excluded from it and you pay depending on usage.